# Allow download on a specific wifi-connection

Tags: wi-fi

Is there a way I can restrict downloads on all networks apart from a specific one which has no bandwidth limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Goto **Data usage**,  **network limitations**. Here you can mark networks as *metered*.

Tested on Android 6 & 7.